# Why don't binfmt_misc with flags "OC", when it works without any flags?

Tags: bash, debian, terminal, kernel, binfmt

I have been testing `binfmt_misc` feature of Linux on Debian 10, and have found that setting the flags to "OC", to use the credentials of the binary instead of interpreter, causes execution to fail silently.

In the POC below, `/tmp/test.sh` is the interpreter, while `qux.go` is the binary. Why is `/tmp/test.sh` executed successfully without flags, when it fails silently with flags "OC"?

**POC**:

```
$ touch qux.go
$ chmod +x qux.go
$ cat <<EOF >/tmp/test.sh                                                                                                                                                                                                          
> #!/bin/sh                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
> echo Golang                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
> EOF      
$ chmod +x /tmp/test.sh 
$ echo ':golang:E::go::/tmp/test.sh:' | sudo tee /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/register 
:golang:E::go::/tmp/test.sh:
$ ./qux.go 
Golang
$ echo -1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/golang 
-1
$ echo ':golang:E::go::/tmp/test.sh:OC' | sudo tee /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/register 
:golang:E::go::/tmp/test.sh:OC
$ ./qux.go # no output
```

Also:

```
mount | grep binfmt_misc
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=28,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=658)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
```

**Bonus**:

Some resources claim that `binfmt_misc` could be used for container-to-host escapes. However, as I see it, the interpreter path is evaluated within the `chroot`'d filesystem of the container, and execution of the interpreter is happening within the container, i.e. `ls -la /` shows the container root (not the host root).

**Resource**:

https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/binfmt-misc.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re being tripped up by two features.

The first is that, when `exec` fails, the shell will look at the contents of the file you’re attempting to run, and if it looks like a shell script, it will interpret it itself. An empty file looks like a shell script. You can see this by running `strace -f ./qux.go`, which shows the failing `exec`, and by changing `qux.go`:

```
$ echo echo Failed Golang > qux.go
$ ./qux.go
Failed Golang
```

The other feature is that the `O` flag [doesn’t work with cascading interpreters](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.11.7/source/fs/exec.c#L1771): in your case, `qux.go` needs an interpreter, but that interpreter itself needs an interpreter, `/bin/sh`, and there are thus two files to interpret, `test.sh` and `qux.go` — but only one final executable file can be handled in `O` mode. The following works:

```
$ cat <<EOF > /tmp/test.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  puts("Golang");
  return 0;
}
EOF
$ make /tmp/test
cc     /tmp/test.c   -o /tmp/test
$ echo ':golang:E::go::/tmp/test:OC' | sudo tee /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/register
:golang:E::go::/tmp/test:OC
$ ./qux.go
Golang
```

Comment: Very detailed. Thanks! I don’t see that “O” doesn’t work with cascading interpreters in the docs, do you?  Why isn’t `binfmt_misc` just executing `/tmp/test.sh` using `exec()` without caring that it’s a shell script? Finally, do you know anything regarding container escapes? E.g `uevent_helper` is executed in the root namespaces, but that doesn’t seem to be the case for `binfmt_misc`?

Comment: So, “OC” flags really just work with native ELF binaries?

Comment: The problem is that `C` implies `O`, and `O` changes the way binaries are supposed to be accessed. I’d have to look up the details, I don’t remember them off-hand. The same goes for container escapes; I do believe I’ve run non-native containers using static QEMU and `binfmt_misc` without a copy of QEMU inside the container, but that might have changed recently, I’d have to check.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure what you mean by *and `binfmt_misc` without a copy of QEMU inside the container* - Also, "OC" flags means that only native ELF binaries can be used as the interpreter?

Comment: `O` implies that only executables which don’t need an interpreter themselves can be used as the interpreter (in practice, native ELF binaries, yes); see [the source of the `NOEXEC` in this case](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/exec.c#L1771): there’s a single `bprm` structure, which needs to encapsulate the final executable being run, but there are two executables to interpret (`test.sh` and `qux.go`).

Comment: Regarding QEMU, I’ve run non-native containers with QEMU only on the host, which means that the `binfmt_misc` interpreter was outside the container...